# Linking error of copy constructor for std::slice using Embarcadero C++ 7.30 for Win32

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
#include <valarray>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void print(const valarray<double> &x) {
    for (int i = 0; i != x.size(); ++i)
    cout << x[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;
}

struct slice_matrix1d {
    int nr;
    std::slice_array<double> elem;
    slice_matrix1d(const std::slice_array<double> &sa, int n): elem(sa),nr(n) {}

    void operator=(double v) { elem = v; }
};

struct matrix1d {
    int nr;
    valarray<double> elem;
    matrix1d(const std::valarray<double> &sa, int n): elem(sa),nr(n) {}

    matrix1d subvec(int i, int j) const {
      std::size_t nr = j - i + 1;
      std::slice s = std::slice(i, nr, 1);
      return matrix1d(elem[s], nr);
    }
    slice_matrix1d subvec(int i, int j) {
      std::size_t nr = j - i + 1;
      std::slice s = std::slice(i, nr, 1);
      return slice_matrix1d(elem[s], nr);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::valarray<double> dva = {1,2,3,4,5};
    matrix1d vec1(dva, 5);
    print(vec1.elem);
    vec1.subvec(1,3) = 0; // <--
    print(vec1.elem);
}
```

When I was trying to compile this program using the compiler Embarcadero C++ 7.30, it gives the following message:

```
C:\Users\typan\OneDrive\Desktop>bcc32x.exe demo_slice_array.cpp

Embarcadero C++ 7.30 for Win32 Copyright (c) 2012-2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
demo_slice_array.cpp:
Turbo Incremental Link 6.90 Copyright (c) 1997-2017 Embarcadero Technologies, Inc.
Error: Unresolved external 'std::slice_array<double>::slice_array<double>(std::slice_array<double>&)' referenced from C:\USERS\TYPAN\APPDATA\LOCAL\TEMP\DEMO_SLICE_ARRAY-768197.O
Error: Unable to perform link
bcc32x.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 2 (use -Xdriver -v to see invocation)
```

My understanding is that inside the member function subvec() we created a temporary std::slice_array and somehow called the copy constructor. But it is quite strange that it does not call the copy constructor std::slice_array provide:
`std::slice_array<double>::slice_array<double>(const std::slice_array<double>&)`
instead it calls:
`std::slice_array<double>::slice_array<double>(std::slice_array<double>&)`
which does not exist and cause the linking error.

My question is: how to change the code so that it can compile using the compiler of Embarcadero C++ 7.30 for Win32? Or actually it is the problem of the compiler itself as it seems to be fine on Visual Studio 2022. Thanks.

Comment: Works [here](https://onlinegdb.com/onKuk5TI9) fine.

Comment: This looks like a bug in the standard library implementation. There shouldn't be any such constructor declared.

Comment: I just compiled both your original and @AnoopRana's example with `bcc32x.exe 7.50` (from Community Edition 10.4) and it compiled fine.

Comment: Why are people using these ancient compilers?